# Bind property of childcontrol to parentcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` (Parent) in which is another `UserControl` (Child). I want to Bind a property in the Child-Control to a property in the Parent-Control. Both `UserControl`s are developed within MVVM. My question now is, how do I access the property of the child-control in the xaml of the parent-control?

Do I have to do something in the code-behind of the child-control or is there another way?

I have an interface called `IPerson` which looks like:

```
public interface IPerson
{
  string Firstname {get;set;}
  string Lastname {get;set;}
}
```

The parent-control (PersonsView) has a `TreeView` on the left side and on the right side there's the child-control (PersonView).

The XAML of Persons-View is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ScM.Contents.View.PersonsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ScM.Contents.ViewModel"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:ScM.Contents.View"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:PersonsViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/ScM.Interface;component/GUI/ScMStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <view:PersonsTreeView Grid.Column="0" Margin="2"
                             OpenPupil="{Binding DataContext.OpenPersonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                             Persons="{Binding DataContext.Persons, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="2" ShowsPreview="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2" />

        <view:PersonView Grid.Column="2" Margin="2"></view:PersonView>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The Person-View consist only of labels and textboxes. The PersonViewModel looks like:

```
internal class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly PersonModel _personModel;

    private IPerson _person;

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        _personModel = new PersonModel();
    }

    public IPerson Person
    {
        get { return _person; }
        set
        {
            _person = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post XAML code what you want to access and show hierarchy of controls. Answers will be dependent on your controls structure.

Comment: Just a remark : DataContext in inherited by default, so you shouldn't need those complex bindings. `OpenPupil="{Binding OpenPersonCommand}"` should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can either name your parent control to point to it using ElementName

```
<ParentControl x:Name=ParentControl>
   <ChildControl SomeChildControlProperty="{Binding SomeParentControlProperty,
                                            ElementName=ParentControl}"/>
</ParentControl>
```

or you can use RelativeSource with FindAncestor :

```
<ParentControl>
   <ChildControl SomeChildControlProperty="{Binding SomeParentControlProperty,
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                          AncestorType={x:Type ParentControl}}}"/>
</ParentControl>
```

I didn't test this code though so the syntax might not be exactly right

Comment: The problem is that the property I would like to set in the child-control is not in the code-behind-file. It's in a separate Class. So I can't access it with this. I get a compiler-error if I try it with `<view:PersonView Person="{Binding SelectedPerson}"/>`

Comment: If it's not in the code-behind-file, then it's not a Property of the child's Control. It looks like you are confusing Views and their DependencyProperties with ViewModels and their standard properties and the binding relations between the two. In that line of xaml you're getting the error on, `Person` is expected to be a property of PersonView, i.e. a dependency property declared in the code behind.

Comment: Yes. And know I want to know if it's possible to bind to the Property in the ViewModel from the View? Or do I have to introduce a DependencyProperty in the Code-Behind of my View?

Comment: `PersonView` should be designed to take a `PersonViewModel` as `DataContext`. Then you would en up with : `<view:PersonView DataContext="{Binding SelectedPerson}"/>`